# High CPU with ImageResizer DiskCache plugin

Tags: imageresizer

We are noticing occasional periods of high CPU on a web server that happens to use ImageResizer. Here are the surprising results of a trace performed with NewRelic's thread profiler during such a spike:

[image: Profiled CPU]

It would appear that the cleanup routine associated with ImageResizer's DiskCache plugin is responsible for a significant percentage of the high CPU consumption associated with this application. We have `autoClean` on, but otherwise we're configured to use the defaults, which I understand are optimal for most typical situations:

```
 <diskCache autoClean="true" />
```

Armed with this information, is there anything I can do to relieve the CPU spikes? I'm open to disabling `autoClean` and setting up a simple nightly cleanup routine, but my understanding is that this plugin is built to be smart about how it uses resources. Has anyone experienced this and had any luck simply changing the default configuration?

This is an ASP.NET MVC application running on Windows Server 2008 R2 with ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache 3.4.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Sampling, or why the profiling is unhelpful

New Relic's [thread profiler](http://blog.newrelic.com/2013/09/19/introducing-thread-profiling-to-the-net-community-and-using-it-to-find-a-performance-bottleneck-in-the-agent/) uses a technique called [sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)#Statistical_profilers) - it does not instrument the calls - and therefore cannot know if CPU usage is actually occurring.

Looking at the provided screenshot, we can see that the backtrace of the cleanup thread (there is only ever one) is frequently found at the [WaitHandle.WaitAny](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitany(v=vs.110).aspx) and [WaitHandle.WaitOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85bbbxt9(v=vs.110).aspx) calls. These methods are low-level synchronization constructs that do not spin or consume CPU resources, but rather efficiently return CPU time back to other threads, and resume on a signal.

Correct profilers should be able to detect idle or waiting threads and eliminate them from their statistical analysis. Because New Relic's profiler failed to do that, there is no useful way to interpret the data it's giving you.

#### If you have more than 7,000 files in /imagecache, here is one way to improve performance

By default, in V3, DiskCache uses 32 subfolders with 400 items per folder (1000 hard limit). Due to imperfect hash distribution, this means that you may start seeing cleanup occur at as few as 7,000 images, and you will start thrashing the disk at ~12,000 active cache files.

This [is explained in the DiskCache documentation - see subfolders section](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/diskcache).

I would suggest setting `subfolders="8192"` if you have a larger volume of images. A higher subfolder count increases overhead slightly, but also increases scalability.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping you'd chime in. I'll try you suggestions, but your insights on `WaitHandle` are especially helpful. That confirms my understanding of how those primitives work, and leads me to believe I'm barking up the wrong tree wrt CPU consumption.

Comment: @Lillith River - what is the current recommendation? We have well over one million images, and once that subfolder cap is hit, the server blows up. Is there a practical limit here / better way of dealing with a large number of images? We do have a CDN sitting in front of the app.